# I have switched off vs I switched off

Tags: grammar

Please, help!

> I have switched off the light before going out this morning.

or

> I switched off the light before going out this morning.

What sentence is correct in BrE? Could you explain it please?

Comment: Google **present perfect vs past tense** for sites such as the following and then tell us which one you think is correct.    https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html

Comment: Thanks! But why is necessary Past Simple? 1. We use the past simple for past events or actions which have no connection to the present. (the connection is - this morning). 2. We use the past simple with a finished time word (last week, last month, yesterday): time word - this morning.

Comment: In my keys of exercises is Past Simple.

Comment: I thought that you could explain it.

Comment: before going out this morning happened in the past, even if the past is only a few hours or a few minutes ago so you should use past simple.